# trying to compare the average of a column with each value of column- WITHOUT USING Nested or SubQUERY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

this is how my data looks.

[image]

I want to find out the Business Entities who has Rate greater than the average rate. There is more data in the database- this is just part of it

Query I used :

```
SELECT A.BusinessEntityID, A.Rate, AVG(B.Rate) as AverageRate
FROM HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory AS A
INNER JOIN HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory AS B ON B.BusinessEntityID = A.BusinessEntityID - 1
GROUP BY A.BusinessEntityID, A.Rate
HAVING A.Rate > AVG(B.Rate)
Order By A.BusinessEntityID
```

I got this result

I get different average for each row/id but it should be the average of the whole Rate column and be 1 value

[image: Result]

Comment: Why can't you use a subquery?

Comment: we have been asked to try it without using sub query

Comment: Are you allowed to use a CTE?

Comment: Could you just join the table to itself but not on any columns, group by the first table's ID and use the average of the second copy's values? like SELECT a.id, a.val, AVG(b.val) AS avg_val FROM foo AS a JOIN foo AS b GROUP BY a.id HAVING val > avg_val . May not be a good idea but satisfies the parameters of the question. If this works I'll make it an answer.

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) for as long as it sees fit. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` here, and then get the average rate for all entities from the cross applied table. Basically you change your `INNER JOIN` to a `CROSS APPLY` and remove the join condition. The query would look like this:

```
SELECT
    A.BusinessEntityID
    ,A.Rate
    ,AverageRate = AVG(B.Rate)
FROM HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory AS A
CROSS APPLY HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory AS B 
GROUP BY
    A.BusinessEntityID
    ,A.Rate
HAVING A.Rate > AVG(B.Rate)
ORDER BY A.BusinessEntityID;
```

As GMB mentioned, `CROSS APPLY` only works in SQL Server. But `CROSS JOIN` should also work in this query in MySql.

```
SELECT
    A.BusinessEntityID
    ,A.Rate
    ,AverageRate = AVG(B.Rate)
FROM HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory AS A
CROSS JOIN HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory AS B 
GROUP BY
    A.BusinessEntityID
    ,A.Rate
HAVING A.Rate > AVG(B.Rate)
ORDER BY A.BusinessEntityID;
```

Comment: @Button:  `CROSS APPLY` is SQL Server syntax, while your question is tagged MySQL. Which database are you actually using?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you have been forbidden to use subqueries. The accepted solution (and you original attempt) to involve a self join and aggregation, which are both expensive tasks.

On the other hand, if you are running MySQL 8.0 (or another database/version that supports window functions - possibly SQL Server since you accepted a solution that uses `CROSS APPLY`), you can do this with a window `avg()` and a subquery.

```
select *
from (
    select 
        BusinessEntityID, 
        Rate, 
        avg(Rate) over() AverageRate
    from mytable
) t
where Rate > AverageRate
```

I would expect that this should be significantly more efficient than the self-join/aggregation solution on a large dataset:

Comment: The question is most likely homework, or otherwise a classroom assignment. In my experience that's the only reason to ask for a specific sub-optimal solution. Also, it looks like your query finds the average for each BusinessEntityID, instead of the average rate for all BusinessEntityIDs. So if BusinessEntityID is unique, no records are returned since AVG(Rate) = Rate in those cases.

Comment: @digital.aaron: yes you must be right, I got fooled by the dataset in the answer, that has different `AverageRate` for every `BusinessEntityID`. I changed the `partition` of the window function accordingly.

Comment: @digital.aaron: I understand that this looks like homework (but could also be dumb management at work). I felt that the optimal solution should be shown as well.

Comment: I think OP just pasted the same screenshot for both the results and sample data. OP also mentioned in a comment `we have been asked to try it without using sub query` which made me come up with the homework hypothesis.